# How to disable default skin for a particular control?

Tags: asp.net-3.5, skins

Is it possible to have a control which does not use the default skin that is specified in a .skin file?

I have a control for which I do **not** want a default skin applied to.

Answer (score 4):

Find this solution in most asp.net books: use EnableTheming

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" EnableTheming="false" />
```

However, it just doesn't work :D. Someone said it's a bug and suggest a workaround: set SkinID to a "not exist" ID

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" SkinID="0" />
```

This works for me but... have a bad feeling

Comment: Sep. 2014: setting EnableTheming to 'false' still doesn't work. Suggested workaround does the trick though.

Comment: EnableTheming="False" is now working, that did the job