# User Control with Specific Theme

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, user-controls

I am creating an ASP.NET User Control that I always want styled a specific way.  Is there a way to override the parent's `Theme` and `StylesheetTheme` properties?

**Edit:** I have tried using the `EnableTheming` property, both in my User Control and in the .aspx page.  Neither worked.

Comment: Take a look of this works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5591671/728795

Comment: @Andrei `EnableTheming` doesn't help